# Given: iptables entry in place; my.cnf properly set up; MySQL user & permissions properly set - but still cannot access MySQL remotely: Suggestions?

Tags: centos, mysql, iptables, remote-access, my.cnf

I would like to access MySQL remotely on an Amazon EC2 CentOS instance (I assume it is CentOS because I use `yum` to update installed applications and libraries).

I believe that `iptables` is set properly, that `my.cnf` is set properly, and that the MySQL user is properly set.

I list all relevant settings in the sections that follow.

---

Contents of `iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.18 on Tue Mar  3 18:02:27 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2620:387248]
[0:0] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[9189:1027277] -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[216:12376] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 24.91.66.190/32 -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Mar  3 18:02:27 2015
```

---

Contents of `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

bind-address=0.0.0.0
port=3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

---

Relevant MySQL setup:

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+-------------+--------------+
| user        | host         |
+-------------+--------------+
| root        | 127.0.0.1    |
| dan         | 24.91.66.190 |
| root        | ::1          |
| dan         | localhost    |
| glassbiller | localhost    |
| root        | localhost    |
+-------------+--------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> select user, host, db, select_priv, insert_priv from mysql.db;
+-------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host         | db               | select_priv | insert_priv |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| dan         | 24.91.66.190 | glassbiller_test | Y           | Y           |
| glassbiller | localhost    | glassbiller\_%   | Y           | Y           |
| dan         | localhost    | glassbiller_test | Y           | Y           |
+-------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Details of server and client MySQL tool:

From `wget -qO- http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7536318/368896) I have confirmed the IP address that I must access from my remote machine, and I am using this.

I have restarted both `iptables` (`sudo service iptables restart`) and `mysql` (`sudo service mysqld restart`).  In fact, at one point I restarted the server.

The password set for user `dan` in MySQL is the same for both the 'localhost' and the '24.91.66.190' entries.

I obtained the IP address *from* which I am trying to access the server (`24.91.66.190`) via the simple URL `http://whatismyip.com`, which I typed into Chrome running on my client Windows machine.

I am attempting to access the remote instance from a Windows machine using the program SQLYog.

Of note: When I SSH into this EC2 instance, I use

`ssh -i myprivatekey.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x` (i.e, I use a public/private key login, with no password - I'm not sure if this is relevant).  I use a Windows program called 'SecureCRT' to log on to my SSH session - I don't use PuTTy.

---

When I attempt to access the MySQL database from my Windows machine at the indicated IP (`24.91.66.190`), with username `dan` and the password set up for user `dan` at that IP on MySQL on the remote server, the connection simply times out.

Having investigated both some documentation for both `iptables` and `mysql`, as well as reviewing dozens of forum postings on the topic, but without finding any possible clues that I have not already tried, I am now posting this question on ServerFault.

Given that I have undertaken all of the above steps, and still cannot access the MySQL instance remotely, what are suggestions for following steps I might take to track down the problem?

---

One last detail: In the `iptables` listing, above, I had changed from `INPUT DROP [3;120]` to `:INPUT ACCEPT [0;0]` - in case that made a difference (it did not).  I plan to change it back as soon as this problem is resolved.

Comment: You check your EC2 security group, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Goodness, the obvious didn't occur to me because I do not own the AWS account and do not have a login for this AWS account's AWS administration page - only access to the specific instance via root-access SSH.  I will contact my client now to ask for access to the AWS control panel - unless there's a way to do this directly from within the SSH command line when logged onto the instance?  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - This is correct.  I obtained the login info, logged on to the AWS console, and set the security group permissions to allow remote access.  Because you answered the question, if you post it as an answer I'll select it as the answer and perhaps someone in the future who runs into this issue will quickly be pointed in the right direction.  Thanks!